# get_user_meta Short Profile Section

Tags: custom-field, users, user-meta, gravatar

Ok so i have added a custom field into the users edit profile page where they can add a link to a url of an image they want. I am currently using this for contribitors and above but i also have a small little profile box on my site that gets a users avatar from gravatar. I used the code from before but changed it around to get the current signed on users authorpic or get the gravatar. See code below

```
$profilepic = get_user_meta('author_pic');
$imgtagbeg = ('<img style="height:52px; width:52px" src="');
$imgtagend = ('"/>');
    if ($profilepic)
        echo $imgtagbeg,$profilepic,$imgtagend; 
    else
        echo get_avatar( $user_email, '52', $default = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=$md5&size=80&default=$default' );
```

What i want to do is if the current user signed in has a avatar linked in his profile field then use that instead of gravatar. But if the author does have a gravatar and has left the field blank in the profile use that or get the default gravatar

**Update:**
What about something like this

```
$userpic = '<img src="link/to/author_pics/$userid.png"';
    if ($userpic)
        echo $userpic;
    else
        echo get_avatar( $user_email, '52', $default = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=$md5&size=80&default=$default' );
```

Instead of relying on a user field just upload an image to a directory and use there userid as the filename then load it else use gravatar. Would that work.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
$userpiccur = wp_get_current_user();
$userpicloc = 'http://avatars.mydomain.com/';
$userpictyp = '.png';
$userpicurl = $userpicloc . $userpiccur->user_login . $userpictyp;
$header_response = get_headers($userpicurl, 1);
$userpicbeg = '<img style="height:52px; width:52px" src="http://avatars.mydomain.com/';
$userpicend = '.png"/>';
if ( strpos( $header_response[0], "404" ) !== false )
    echo $userpicbeg,$userpiccur->user_login,$userpicend;
else
    echo get_avatar( $user_email, '52', $default = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=$md5&size=80&default=$default' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i got it working like i want. Now all i have to do is figure out if i want a user to be able to upload there own image or not.

```
<?
$userpiccur = wp_get_current_user();
$userpicloc = 'http://avatars.mydomain.com/';
$userpictyp = '.png';
$userpicurl = $userpicloc.$userpiccur->user_login.$userpictyp;
$userpicbeg = '<img class="avatar avatar-52 photo" style="height:52px; width:52px" src="';
$userpicend = '"/>';
if (@fopen($userpicurl, "r"))
    echo  $userpicbeg,$userpicurl,$userpicend;
else
    echo get_avatar( $user_email, '52', $default = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=$md5&size=80&default=$default' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the core:

```
function get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single = false) {
    return get_metadata('user', $user_id, $key, $single);
}
```

Pass the user id as the first argument, the key `'author_pic'` as the second and `TRUE` as the third (to get a string value back).

Comment: Can you explain better. I am putting this in a profile template page not functions

Comment: nvm check out my updated question. Let me know if that'll work

Answer (score 1):

Your code in the edit part of the question should work, and also your first part but you need to add the user ID to [get_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) function so use your first code but change the first line to this:

```
$profilepic = get_user_meta($user_id,'author_pic',true);
```

and make sure $user_id hold the user's actual ID.

Comment: Thanks i think i will use my edit part instead. Seems it would be better that way i can control who can add there own custom pic or not.

Comment: you can control better with a meta field and its much easier, but i just remembered that you will need to check if the file exists and not just `if( $userpic)`

Comment: do you think i should use this `$user_login` instead

Comment: Ok so if i need to check for file how do i do that

Comment: Can you check my new update. And tell me if it will work or not.

Comment: the new way is an overkill, you are creating a request for every image, and when they are not found the request takes time, just use php file_exists function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: ok but that will not work for outside servers from what i have herd and read

Comment: yeah but you are checking your server? anyway i still think that using a custom user meta field that will hold the user image URL is much simpler and easier to manage.

Comment: no i am not checking my server i am checking a remote server a cdn. and since file-exists is for local use it would not work. I do agree with it may be simpler to manage but i have already developed a upload box that gets the users login name and uses it as a file name.

Comment: the user meta field was a ok thing but i did not like that fact that the would hot link to an image if they wanted to.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean, well then your code looks about right.